# Git push - "Everything is up to date" - But working tree files don't get updated. what to do?

Tags: git, githooks

**1)** I have a `prime` repo on a `remote server host`.

**2)** I have a `bare` repo on a `remote server host`.

**3)** I have a `clone of the bare` repo with a working tree on my `local computer`, and the bare is setup as a remote on this local repo.

Sometimes, some files are added directly (no staging) by our shared host staff without using the common procedure "git add and commit" - **result:**

We often do git push and it says: "Everything is up to date" (true because the bare gets updated) but the prime doesn't, hence, the `working tree` files aren't there.

I need something (hook, cronjob?) so that, when bare is different from prime, prime must be updated with the latest bare files.

Can we use a hook, or cronjob to force this behavior?

What are our options?

I'm available to chat, if someone has the patience for that.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a post-receive hook set on your bare repo, in order to do, on each push:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/prime/.git --work-tree=/path/to/prime pull bare
```

(no need to '`cd`'  anywhere here, since you specify to `git` where is the repo directory and the working tree).

Provided that the prime repo has a remote named "`bare`".

```
cd /path/to/prime
git remote add bare /path/to/bare.git
```

Comment: I need some time to process this info. I have some questions. Please allow me sometime to understand it and get back with doubts if any. thanks.

Comment: does this imply that, each time the push is made to the bare repo, a new remote branch is associated to the prime repo?

Comment: @MEM no, no new branch is created. A workspace (`/path/to/prime`) is updated, based on the content registered in a bare git repo (`/path/to/prime/.git`) pulled into `/path/to/prime/.git`. By default, only the `master` branch is checked out and updated by the pull.

Answer (score 0):

You can create remote tracking branch. It will not update your local tree with new changes automatically but it will tell you by how many commits your remote is ahead of your local repo.
to create remote tracking branch

git branch --track [new branch name]  [remote branch name]